# Iframe (facebook) content not loading in Iphone after IOS15 upgrade

Tags: ios, facebook, iframe, safari, ios15

We are trying to embed a Facebook page in an iframe and the content is not loading after the ios is upgraded to ios15. The same application is working fine in IOS14. This issue is seen both safari and chrome browsers after IOS15 upgrade. The same application works fine in Android Mobiles and Desktop mobiles. The embed space goes blank. Are there any known issues with IOS15 with respect to iframe? Any pointers to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

`iOS`
`safari`
`iframe`
`Facebook`
`ios15`